# Copying data from master sheet to workbooks based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel, paste

The below code struggles at the final "paste section". It opens up the new spreadsheet which I want to paste in but instead pastes in the underlying sheet where the data already exists. Any ideas on how to get this into the new sheet?

```
Option Explicit

Sub newfiles()  
    Dim personname As Variant
    Dim workbookname As Variant
    Dim namerange As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim personame As Variant
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer

    k = Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("N3:N" & k).Copy

    With Range("XFC1:XFC" & k)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    End With

    namerange = Range("XFC10000").End(xlUp).Row        

    For i = 1 To namerange
        personname = Range("XFC" & i).Value
        Workbooks.Add 
        workbookname = ActiveWorkbook.Name

        Windows("Test 1.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select

        Cells.Copy
        Range("A1").Select
        Windows(workbookname).Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select

        With Cells
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        End With
```

Comment: Your problem lies within your use of `.Select` and `.Activate`. Instead you should learn yourself to explicitly reference workbooks and sheets by declaring them. You should read up on how to avoid using select.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some recommendations:

1. Don't use `Variant` unless you have to.
2. Use descriptive variable names (eg `LastRow` is more descriptive than `k`).
3. Don't use `Integer` for row counting variables. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. It is recommended [always to use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA.
4. Define a worksheet for every `Range()`, `Cells()`, etc. otherwise Excel cannot know in which worksheet the range is and it tries to guess the worksheet (which results in unpredictive behavior).
5. Set the new added workbook to a variable so you can access it easily later: `Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add`
6. Avoid using `.Select` or `.Activate` they are not needed to perform actions. Instead directly reference a worksheet/range.

So you probably need to modify the following code but it should give you an idea how to do it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub newfiles()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet 'source worksheet
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'define your worksheet name here

    Dim LastRowA As Long
    LastRowA = wsSrc.Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    wsSrc.Range("N3:N" & LastRowA).Copy

    With wsSrc.Range("XFC1:XFC" & LastRowA)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    End With

    Dim LastRowNameRange As Long
    LastRowNameRange = wsSrc.Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, "XFC").End(xlUp).Row


    Dim PersonName As String
    Dim wbNew As Workbook

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To LastRowNameRange
        PersonName = wsSrc.Range("XFC" & iRow).Value 'note that you never use the PersonName variable

        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy

        With wbNew.Worksheets(1).Cells 'directly access the first sheet in the new workbook
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        End With
    Next iRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Windows(workbookname).Activate` should be `Workbooks(workbookname).Activate`

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the issue. It has copied the data, opens up the new workbook where I want to paste. Yet for some reason with the final step it is pasting in the one behind and not the one that I want. I'm baffled